# Can you over-water a staghorn fern root-ball?

Tags: watering, ferns

I have a large staghorn fern , the "root ball" is about 14" tall and about 12" in diameter. I bring it in in winter . I water it at about 2 week intervals by using a 60 ml syringe to put about 600 ml of water into the top of the root ball. Today ,a couple drops of water dripped out for the first time. Each winter it looses about 10 fronds (that does not make much difference in the appearance) , I expect because of the low humidity in the house. Should I be concerned that a little water drained out of the root-ball ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a concern so long as any excess water is able to drain away readily, which is apparently the case for you, since a few drops did drain away.